# how to fetch path of driectory in drupal 8 module code

Tags: drupal-8

I am creating a drupal 8 module . under that module a custom file folder is created I want to pass this directory in

$info_files = file_scan_directory('[path]', '/.*.pdf$/');

how can I give this path for file folder in a module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use like this

$my_url = drupal_get_path('module', '[Your_module_name]') . "/yourdirectoryname";
    $option = array();
    $info_files = file_scan_directory($my_url, '/.*.pdf$/',$option);

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, I will take care of this.